# Usage (showing, hiding) of serverside Kendo tab strip in MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-tabstrip

I have a `kendoGrid()` and I am attaching a `KendoTabStrip()` with multiple tabs beneath it that contain additional data for the grid items.
The whole things is contained in a toggle panel.

My Question:
I want the whole(!) tabstrip only to be displayed if I actually need it:
on selecting any grid element or on pressing a specific button.

Since it is (apparently) not possible to hide the tabstrip initially using a attribute or something, I would have to hide the tabstrip with the `.hide()` function within a `document.ready()` function and `show()` it again on the both events button, change.

I really don't think that that's a good approach...

Is it possible to toggle the collapse state by a function?

*I should admit: I am quite a newbie in the areas of JS, Kendo and MVC.
In order to proceed more efficiently I wanted to ask some basic things about my problem. Thanks!*

Comment: How about using Grid Detail Template. Each row is collapsible for more information. Check out this demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate

Comment: Thx for the tip. Unfortunately this is not what I want...Is it possible to toggle the collapse state by a function?

Comment: Yes, collapseRow and expandRow changes master row state.

Comment: Thx, pretty cool. Is it also possible not to toggle but to explicitly show/hide?